# Creating a task for wcf Async, doesnt await

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, task, async-await

Basically, when my autocompletetextbox changes text it updates from `WCF` service (with photos), problem is:

```
Task taskA = new Task(() => listanomes.queryAsync(argumentos, 2, 3, query));
```

The task doesn't start as soon as I start it, so the list I need is empty.

```
private async void tbA_destinatario_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await buscaAC();
    await fotos();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Pessoa temp in listaPessoas)
    {
        if (listaimgs.Count == 0)
            break;
        temp.Imagem = listaimgs[i];
        i++;
        listaPessoas[i] = temp;
    }
    tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = listaPessoas;
}

private async Task buscaAC()
{
    ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient listanomes = new ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient();
    string query = "select nome,id_user, foto from tbl_conexoes, tbl_users where((tbl_conexoes.id_con2 = @var1 AND id_con1 = id_user) OR (tbl_conexoes.id_con1 = @var1 AND id_con2 = id_user)) AND upper(nome) LIKE upper(@var2)  ORDER BY nome LIMIT 0, 5";
    List<string> argumentos = new List<string>();
    argumentos.Add(Convert.ToString(id));
    argumentos.Add("%" + tbA_destinatario.Text + "%");

    //listanomes.listautilizadoresAsync(id, tbA_destinatario.Text);
    listanomes.queryCompleted += listanomesautocomplete;
    Task taskA = new Task(() => listanomes.queryAsync(argumentos, 2, 3, query));
    taskA.Start();
    await taskA;
}

private async Task fotos()
{
    ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient dlfotos = new ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient();

    dlfotos.listadlFotoCompleted += dlfotos_listadlFotoCompleted;
    Task taskA = new Task(() => dlfotos.listadlFotoAsync(nomeimgs));
    taskA.Start();

    await taskA;
}
```

Comment: With `async-await` use only `Task.Run` to start tasks. In C#, methods are always CamelCased and async methods should be suffixed **Async**. Why aren't you using asynchronous proxies for WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trying to further analyze you code, this is certainly a problem:

```
Task taskA = new Task(() => listanomes.queryAsync(argumentos, 2, 3, query));
```

You're doing fire-and-forget here. When you start your task, it will be instantly completed, while `queryAsync` will continue executing in the background.

You should rewrite your code without using `Task` constructor explicitly. I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: It did not completed, my list which should be filled when that task completes is still empty. When i debug, that task only start after tbA_destinatario_TextChanged finishes. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @The outer task *did*, then inner task which you create with `listanomes.queryAsync()` did *not*. To see what I meant, try this: `Task taskA = new Task(() => listanomes.queryAsync(argumentos, 2, 3, query).Wait())`, note the `Wait()`. This is for your to understand the problem, but using `Wait()` like this is a code smell, either.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but i tried that code and the same result is the same, i cannot await for a void function. Is there any workaround for this situation?

Comment: @user3285630, exactly at what line of the code do you see "cannot await void"?

Comment: Exactly the line where i use await for taskA. This for example: Task taskA = new Task( async () => await listanomes.queryAsync(argumentos, 2, 3, query));  but if i taskA.Start(); then Await taskA; it doesn't give any error, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @user3285630, nowhere above I suggested you doing `new Task( async () => await listanomes.queryAsync(argumentos, 2, 3, query))`, this is **wrong**. That said, what is the signature of `queryAsync` method?  If it's `void`, that's *another* problem. That method should return `Task`. Where does it come from, is it also your code?

Comment: @user3285630, [async-await tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) has links to some great resources. Make sure to study them, it'd help to understand how things work.

Comment: That method can't return anything else besides void, because its a queryAsync(i tried something else and it gives error)

Comment: @user3285630, then there has to be an event on the same object, like `QueryAsyncCompleted`, which you wrap as a `Task`: [How to: Wrap EAP Patterns in a Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't understood how to wrap EAP, but basically my problem is awaiting for a queryasync, i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753719/how-to-await-for-querycompleted-event BUT unfortunately i can't apply that to my code

Comment: I FOUND IT! 
public static Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> QueryAsync<TResult>(this DataServiceQuery<TResult> query)
        {
            return Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>.Factory.FromAsync(query.BeginExecute, query.EndExecute, null);
        } 
Now i am trying to find out how to work with this, this was also used on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753719/how-to-await-for-querycompleted-event

Comment: That's the [APM pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx?Redirected=true). It doesn't really matter if you wrap EAP or APM pattern as `Task`. As long as you've learnt how to do it, get rid of `new Task()`, it's redundant.

Comment: Oh yes i see that now, thanks alot, but i am still trying to use APM pattern, i read that link, i am a little bit more confused to be honest. Maybe i should create another Question. What do you think?

Comment: I really think you should read the links listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) first, starting from [this one](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and then ask another question about anything you might still not understand.

Comment: The thing is i don't have much time left, am going to read what i can and create a new question, thanks alot man!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to await the tasks you call inside the delegates. For example:

```
Task taskA = new Task( async () => await listanomes.queryAsync(argumentos, 2, 3, query));
```

But I don't really see a reason why you create a separate Task. You could just use:

```
await listanomes.queryAsync(argumentos, 2, 3, query);
```

Instead of creating `taskA`, starting it and awaiting it.

Comment: Cannot await 'void' using both solutions, thanks for your response anyways

Comment: Well I assumed that the methods return Task, because the naming convention says that when method name ends with Async it means it returns Task.

Comment: `new Task( async () => await listanomes.queryAsync(..))` is pretty much the same as `new Task(() => listanomes.queryAsync(..))`. You're right though the OP doesn't really need to create the outer `Task` at all.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I think there is something wrong with the method design.

Comment: Well, if i do listanomes.queryAsync(..), the list(which is supose to be filled in that queryasync when it completes) is empty because it will only do the queryasync after tbA_destinatario_TextChanged finishes