# APM pattern, Await Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

I need help on how to use APM pattern, i am now reading some articles, but i am afraid i don't have much time. What i really want is to get all the persons(data from db) then get the photos and put it on a autocompletebox
Code:

```
void listanomesautocomplete(object sender, ServicosLinkedIN.queryCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result[0] != "")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Result.Count(); i = i + 3)
                {
                    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
                    pessoa.Nome = e.Result[i];
                    pessoa.Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Result[i + 1]);
                    if (e.Result[i + 2] == "")
                        pessoa.Imagem = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/default_perfil.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    else
                    {
                        ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient buscaimg = new ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient();
                        buscaimg.dlFotoAsync(e.Result[i + 2]);
                        buscaimg.dlFotoCompleted += buscaimg_dlFotoCompleted;//when this completes it saves into a public bitmapimage and then i save it into pessoa.Imagem
                        //basicly, what happends, the listadlfotosasync only happends after this function
                        //what i want is to wait until it completes and have into the class novamsg
                        pessoa.Imagem = img;//saving the photo from dlFotoAsync           

                    }
                    listaPessoas.Add(pessoa);
                }

                tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = null;
                tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = listaPessoas;

                BackgroundWorker listapessoas = new BackgroundWorker();
                listapessoas.DoWork += listapessoas_DoWork;
                listapessoas.RunWorkerAsync();
                tb_lerdestmsg.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = null;
                tb_lerdestmsg.Text = "Não encontrado";
            }
        }
```

Comment: What i need is this  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753719/how-to-await-for-querycompleted-event OR(thesame) http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/dataservicequery-tresult/queryasync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to address here:

- The `listanomesautocomplete` event handler should be `async`. Handle and report all exceptions possibly thrown inside it (generally, this rule applies to any event handler, but it's even more important for `async` event handlers, because the asynchronous operation inside your handler continues outside the scope of the code which has fired the event).
- Register the `dlFotoCompleted` event handler first, then call `dlFotoAsync`. Do not assume that `dlFotoAsync` will be *always* executed asynchronously.
- Think about the case when another `listanomesautocomplete` is fired while the previous operation is still pending. This well may happen as a result of the user's action. You may want to cancel and restart the pending operation (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639075/1768303)), or just queue a new one to be executed as soon as the pending one has completed (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21424084/1768303)).

Back to the question, it's the [EAP pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you need to wrap as `Task`, not APM. Use `TaskCompletionSource` for that. The relevant part of your code may look like this:

```
async void listanomesautocomplete(object sender, ServicosLinkedIN.queryCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result[0] != "")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Result.Count(); i = i + 3)
        {
            Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
            pessoa.Nome = e.Result[i];
            pessoa.Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Result[i + 1]);
            if (e.Result[i + 2] == "")
                pessoa.Imagem = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/default_perfil.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
            {
                // you probably want to create the service proxy 
                // outside the for loop
                using (ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient buscaimg = new ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient())
                {
                    FotoCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
                    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Image>();

                    handler = (sHandler, eHandler) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // you can move the code from buscaimg_dlFotoCompleted here,
                            // rather than calling buscaimg_dlFotoCompleted
                            buscaimg_dlFotoCompleted(sHandler, eHandler);

                            tcs.TrySetResult(eHandler.Result);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            tcs.TrySetException(ex);
                        }
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        buscaimg.dlFotoCompleted += handler;
                        buscaimg.dlFotoAsync(e.Result[i + 2]);

                        // saving the photo from dlFotoAsync
                        pessoa.Imagem = await tcs.Task;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        buscaimg.dlFotoCompleted -= handler;
                    }
                }
            }
            listaPessoas.Add(pessoa);
        }

        tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = null;
        tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = listaPessoas;

        BackgroundWorker listapessoas = new BackgroundWorker();
        listapessoas.DoWork += listapessoas_DoWork;
        listapessoas.RunWorkerAsync();
        tb_lerdestmsg.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = null;
        tb_lerdestmsg.Text = "Não encontrado";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void listanomesautocomplete(object sender, ServicosLinkedIN.queryCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Result[0] != "")
            {

                List<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new List<Pessoa>();

                for (int i = 0; i < e.Result.Count(); i = i + 3)
                {
                    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
                    pessoa.Nome = e.Result[i];
                    pessoa.Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Result[i + 1]);
                    if (e.Result[i + 2] == "")
                        pessoa.Imagem = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/default_perfil.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    else
                    {
                        ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient buscaimg = new ServicosLinkedIN.ServicosClient();
                        buscaimg.dlFotoAsync(e.Result[i + 2]);
                        //THIS ACTUALLY WORKS!!!
                        //THE THREAD WAITS FOR IT!
                        buscaimg.dlFotoCompleted += (s, a) =>
                        {
                            pessoa.Imagem = ConvertToBitmapImage(a.Result);
                        };
                    }
                    listaPessoas.Add(pessoa);
                }

                if (tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource == null)
                {

                    tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = listaPessoas;
                }
                tb_lerdestmsg.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = null;
                tb_lerdestmsg.Text = "Não encontrado";
            }
        }
```

Man, i am not even mad, i am amazed.
Noseratio, you answer gave me an idea and it actually worked!!
Thanks a lot man, i can't thank you enough ;)

Comment: No problem, but this code is still incorrect. Think about what happens if `dlFotoCompleted` is fired in 1 second after you have called `dlFotoAsync`. The whole `for ` loop may be finished by then.

Comment: Impossible i think, the way i tested, only 1 thread did all the work, but i will keep stressing the program, once again thank you for your time!

Comment: Something is wrong... i replicate exactly the code on other page and it doesn't work. I observed the debugging on the working on, and its pretty much magic, really, if (tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource == null)
                {

                    tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource = listaPessoas;
                } if you check that code above it makes no sense right? after the first update on itemsource it shouldn't work anymore... but it does i have checked the whole solution by 'tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource' and nothing appears, something is filling the tbA_destinatario.ItemsSource, i wonder what.

Comment: You really should be using `TaskCompletionSource` to await for the event, similarly to how it's done in my answer. I can't help debugging this.

Comment: Oh i copied again exactly, and it worked... after i deliver this project (in about 5 hours) i will check out those links you gave and not do ugly workarounds